# Trying to publish SharePoint Webpart via CLI

Tags: sharepoint, command-line-interface, web-parts

I have a SharePoint application already published in our test tenant.  I am trying to get the CLI commands set so that I can add it into the build of a GOCD pipeline.  I have powershell open and O365 CLI installed on my pc.  I have already authenticated with the test tenant by issuing the login command and then opening up the URL in the browser to retrieve the code.

In the powershell I change directory to where the package is built.  When I issue this command and hit enter there is a pause for several seconds and then I am brought back to the command line.  When I look in the app catalog the modified time is still the same.  Am I missing something? The ID matches what is in the app catalog.

m365 spo app deploy --id 11C328F0-B25E-4F1E-AC1D-6BF74AE3AE33 --appCatalogUrl https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/apps

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  I completely forgot to add the overwrite.

m365 spo app add --filePath ./my.sppkg --appCatalogUrl https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/apps --overwrite